# javado Doclet enum - How to get possible values from an enum to use in my own doclet?

Tags: enums, javadoc, doclet

When using javadoc, enums are usually documented like that:

```
/**
* Doc for enum
*/
public enum Something {
  /**
  * First thing
  */
  FIRST_THING,
  /**
  * Second thing
  */
  SECOND_THING;
}
```

My problem is that, using JavaDoc Doclets, I can get the classDoc of that enum ( [Javadoc ClassDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/ClassDoc.html) ), but I am not able to get the comments of the possible values, or even the possible values itself. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`enumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/ClassDoc.html#enumConstants%28%29) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Have seen it also in the API a moment ago! :-)